# Correct Structure Marshalling

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling

I have a structure:

```
typedef struct _wfs_bcr_caps
{
WORD             wClass;
BOOL             bCompound;
BOOL             bCanFilterSymbologies;
LPUSHORT         lpwSymbologies;
DWORD            dwGuidLights[32];
LPSTR            lpszExtra;
BOOL             bPowerSaveControl;
BOOL             bAntiFraudModule;
}
```

I need to make a correct copy of this structure in C#.

But I have a problem with LPUSHORT type. Could some one help me to set up correct marshal attributes for lpwSymbologies property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LPUSHORT` is just long pointer to `ushort` value. You can marshal it as `IntPtr` and than read a value using `Marshal.ReadInt16` or `Marshal.ReadInt32` (since you are using unsigned short). Another option is described in this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12121/P/Invoke%20MSDN%20tutorial), `Unmanaged to Managed type translation table`, e.g. marshalling `LP<struct>` into `[In] ref <struct>`

Comment: Thank you for your message. Unfortunately I'm not a receiver. I need to send this structure to c++ library via PostMessage.

Comment: Than you can declare it as `IntPtr` and use `Marshal.WriteInt16` method or its overloads when creating it (before `PostMessage`)